# How can I get process id of a process that opens a particular port using C program?

Tags: c, networking, tcp, port

I want to find out which process is opening a port, how can I do it in c code? Thanks!

Comment: What operating system? Oh, and [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Why? when 'netstat' already exists?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you check out the source code for the "netstat" command.  `netstat --inet -p` will give you the information you want so the code will have all that is necessary to read that.

http://freecode.com/projects/net-tools

Answer (score 2):

If you dont mind doing it from the commandline, just use

netstat -anp | grep [port you want]